# Go: Represent path without query string

Tags: go

How do I represent a path without query string?

Eg.:

- `www.example.com/user` instead of
- `www.example.com/user?id=1`

The following code didn't work:

Go:

```
if r.URL.Path[4:] != "" {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add parameters to an url, you would use [`Values()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_Values).

That means, an URL without any parameters would have its 'Values' length set to 0:

```
if len(r.URL.Query()) == 0 {
}
```

That should be the same as the [`r.URL.RawQuery`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) suggested by [Dewy Broto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017302/dewy-broto) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189523/go-represent-path-without-query-string/26189617#comment41102134_26189617):

```
if r.URL.RawQuery == "" {
}
```

Or you can check for the presence if the key '`id`' in the `Values()` map.

```
if r.URL.Query().Get("id") == "" {
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: I used a simpler r.URL.Query() which gives me a map. However, if r.URL.Query != nil didn't work.

Comment: @user3918985 did you try `r.URL.Values()`, to see if that works better?

Comment: yup, I get this error: r.URL.Values undefined (type *url.URL has no field or method Values)

Comment: same error. I removed Values and it somehow still didn't register.

Comment: @user3918985 but at least, it does compile, right? I mean `URL.Query` (http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query) does return `Values`, on which you can try `Get("id")`

Comment: @DewyBroto True. I have included that option in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @tommywild yes, I removed the extra `.Values`.

Answer (score 7):

```
func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.example.com/user?id=1", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // get host
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.Host) // Output: www.example.com

    // path without query string
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.URL.Path) // Output: /user

    // get query string value by key
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.URL.Query().Get("id")) // Output: 1

    // raw query string
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.URL.RawQuery) // Output: id=1
}
```

Go [play](http://play.golang.org/p/oqSxCV89vP)